# include the jpeg plugin in my application

Tags: qt, plugins, jpeg

I made a Qt GUI application that loads jpeg files. On my development system (Win7) where I have installed the QtSDK (4.7.3) it works.
When I move the application and some required dlls (like QtGui4.dll and others) to another system, where the QtSDK isnt installed, the program executes, but cant load jpegs. 
I read, that i have to add the jpeg plugin, but I dont know how.

I already tried this in my main.cpp:

```
Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(qjpeg);
```

together with this in my project file:

```
QTPLUGIN += qjpeg
```

But I got the error:

```
cannot find -lqjpegd
```

I dont care if I include this plugin in a dynamic or a static way. I just need my application to work on other systems. I prefer the way that is simpler. What I tried is the static way, right? How can I just include it as a dll file in my application ?
I also checked my

```
mingw\plugins\imageformats
```

directory and there is really no qjpeg.dll. But there are:

qjpeg4.dll
qjpegd4.dll
libqjpeg4.a

Than i tried it with:

```
Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(qjpeg4);
QTPLUGIN += qjpeg4
```

But got the same error msg. Whats wrong?

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 3):

Copy the `plugins\imageformats` folder into your application directory. 
In your main(), add this

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
QString sDir = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath();
a.addLibraryPath(sDir+"/plugins");
```

Comment: `QApplication a(argc, argv);`

Comment: It still doesn't work ... The output (using QPrinter to print to pdf) does not have any images. Any workaround?